# await/async in asp.net not working properly?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm using asp.net core 1.1 and encounter a strange situation when some users cannot get the updated data.

```
 public virtual async Task<ActionResult> Deposit(decimal money, string customerId)
{
     var customer = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(customerId);
    customer.Fund+= money;  // a few customers does not get the money !!
    await _userManager.UpdateAsync(customer);  // asp.net identity 2.0 usermanager
    await UpdateOrderMoneyCollect(customer, money, debt);
}
```

The correct process is that customer must get updated the fund first before sending to update the order. From my own test, it works fine in local and website. But somehow, some users apparently does not get the correct values.

Is there anything wrong with the way I'm doing ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: This might be the problem: `customer.Fund+= money`. What if two requests are targeting the same customer in the same time?

Comment: thanks for your input. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is `await UpdateOrderMoneyCollect(customer, money, debt);` causing any side effect to the customer?

Comment: @Giulio actually, without the UpdateOrderMoneyCollect, the problem still persists, even with only me as a tester.

Comment: To test, use the AsyncLock to allow only one thread to deposit: https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/wiki/AsyncLock

Comment: For now, use a `static` instance so that it will work even if there are multiple controllers.

Comment: As @YacoubMassad suggested try to test multiple customer edit.
A not related suggestion is to always include a CancellationToken in your async/await calls.

Comment: If this causes performance issues, you need a way to allow two concurrent requests acting on *different* customers.

Comment: checkout c# 8 new feature IAsyncEnumerable. it uses pull model instead of push model so there might be less unwanted behaviors